# Combining code coverage reports in javascript for coveralls

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, coveralls, blanket.js

I have node.js based projects that also include client side code. I have 2 separate unit test suites, 1 for front end and 1 for back end. I currently have mocha running using blanket for code coverage and piping the result into the coveralls module like so:

```
mocha --require blanket --reporter mocha-lcov-reporter server/test/unit | ./node_modules/.bin/coveralls
```

I essentially need to combine the output of these 2 test runs (server and client):

```
mocha --require blanket --reporter mocha-lcov-reporter server/test/unit
```

and

```
mocha --require blanket --reporter mocha-lcov-reporter client/test/unit
```

and pipe that into the coveralls module.

Is this possible? How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I used gulp and a coveralls plugin to accomplish this:

http://gulpjs.com/

https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-coveralls